# How to append something to a page style defined by \fancypagestyle

Tags: tex-core, fancyhdr, etoolbox

Some other codes can be appended to a macro by tools from `etoolbox`, for example, `\apptocmd`.

I wonder if there are similar ways to append something to a page style defined by `\fancypagestyle` from the package `fancyhdr`?

**Example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \chead{title}
}

\newcommand{\apptopagestyle}[2]{...}

\begin{document}
\apptopagestyle{mypagestyle}{\cfoot{\thepage}}
% After this, the content of "mypagestyle" is "\fancyhf{}\chead{title}\cfoot{\thepage}".
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\pagestyle{mypagestyle}` simply redefines the parameters for fancyhdr then executes `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal name of the pagestyle is `ps@mypagestyle`, so the following definition works:

```
\newcommand{\apptopagestyle}[2]{\csappto{ps@#1}{#2}}
```